# How to load a .env file's environment variables into both Bash and Fish shells on startup?

Tags: bash, fish

I want to have a .env file with a bunch of name-value pairs, like:

```bash
VAR1=xxx
VAR2=yyy

# sample C include dir use case
INCLUDE_DIR=/etc/include/xxx
```

I want these variables to be available in both `bash` and `fish` shells, such that I can access them in either shell at any time like `echo $VAR1`.

Comment: I'd look into using [direnv](https://direnv.net/) for your needs. Basically, you put your env in `.envrc` and direnv hook looks for that file up from the current directory by hooking into PROMPT_COMMAND. It supports hooks for all the common shells like bash, zsh, tcsh and fish.

Answer (score -3):

1. Create a file in `~/.env` (for example) with the variables in the format above.
2. Add the following to the bottom of `~/.bash_rc`:

```bash
source ~/.env
```

3. Add the following to the bottom of `~/.config/fish/config/fish`:

```
export (envsubst < ~/.env | sed '/^\s*#/d; /^$/d')
```

This command reads the `.env` file, removes blank lines and comments, and then sets them as environment variables.

Comment: While a `.env` file may be *syntactically* acceptable to `bash`, the quoting rules are different and it is generally not safe to source a `.env` file as if it were a shell script.